# Complementary generic types

Tags: java, oop, generics, typing

**Premise:** In my project I have two generically typed interfaces defining Request and Response respectively. A request is processed to yield a response, hence every response is built based on a request. A Processor interface processes a request to build the corresponding response.

**Code:** The request and response interfaces are:

```
interface Request<T1>
```

and

```
interface Response<T2>
```

respectively, where `T2` and `T1` represent generic request and response types (I am deliberately calling them by different names for clarity).

Now, since T2 *is a* Request, and T1 *is a* response, so the above code evolves to:

```
interface Request<T1 extends Response>
```

and

```
interface Response<T2 extends Request>
```

*Note that: Request and Response interfaces do not share any inheritance relationship - what the above code only intends to communicate is: Request is typed with only some other type which is-a Response.*

Now, consider the Request interface: since Response is again typed, and the response built out of a request will be tied to the original request type, hence, the above code evolves to:

```
interface Request<T1 extends Response<? extends Request<T1>>>
```

and

```
interface Response<T2 extends Request<? extends Response<T2>>
```

Now, the Processor interface is defined as:

```
interface Processor<R1 extends Request<R2>, R2 extends Response<R1>> {
    R2 process(R1 request);
}
```

**Concrete classes:**

Request implementation:

```
class ConcreteRequest implements Request<ConcreteResponse> {
    ConcreteResponse response;
    ...`
}
```

Response implementation:

```
class ConcreteResponse implements Response<ConcreteRequest> {
    ConcreteRequest request;
    ...
}
```

Processor implementation:

```
class ConcreteProcessor implements Processor<ConcreteRequest, ConcreteResponse> {
    ConcreteResponse process(ConcreteRequest request) {
    ...
    }
}
```

**Question:** Is the above code over-designed? Is there a simplified way to represent a tuple of complementary input-output objects?

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain this a little more ... `Request<T1 extends Response>` Why would `T1` a `Request` extend a `Response` type?

Comment: @Vijay: T1 is not a response, it is the generic type which indicates the response it will eventually generate if processed... for example List<String> means a List which contains String objects as its elements... is that what you were asking about?

Comment: What do you gain by using generics with `Request` and `Response`? A simple, concrete example would go a long way here.

Comment: @David: ... which is where my question is: Is the above code over-designed? :) I think I see your answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've totally misunderstood your question, you don't - and shouldn't - use generic for this kind of problem.  Using polymorphism and/or composition will be much more appropriate.  For example, if you need to integrate a copy of the request in the response (hardly necessary but thinkable) then you can add a reference to a request object in your response class.

Technically, this reference to a `Request` object could be defined using a type; however, you shouldn't do that because it will always be a `Request` object (either a base class or a derived subclass) and not some kind of arbitrary class that could change with each instanciation of a response.

You use generic when the type of each referenced object is totally different (for example, a `List <String>` or a `List<Request>`: there is no subclassing relationship between a `String` and a `Request` object) or when the use of polymorphism will not be sufficient because you are defining one or more new virtual functions in a subclass that are not present in the superclass.

Building a `Response` to be based on a `Request` because a `Request` is processed to yield a `Response` is definitely not the way to go and your current `Processor` interface is a testimony to that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand your point as to why Generics is not applicable: "no subclassing relationship" between possible types addressed by the generic type, but why do you think "Building a Response to be based on a Request ... is definitely not the way to go ... Processor interface is a testimony to that." - is it leading to any anti-pattern? If you could please explain. Thanks!

Comment: The fact that a Response will be build and send back after a Request doesn't mean that there is a hierarchical super-class / sub-class relationship between these two.  From the point of view of OOP, a Response and a Request are two different objects belonging to two different classes.  It's possible that they will share some common functions, interface or other elements (it all depends on your code) but you shouldn't confuse these shared elements with the fact that functionnaly, a Reply will be sent back as an answer to a Request.

Comment: why do you think Request and Response share an inheritance relationship? (Is that suggestive from my code snippet? If so, I am updating with a note) In fact, I use composition to maintain references of one within the other. the only inheritance is the generic type which is defined with the Request for example; which means that a Request is generically tied to another type which is some sort of a Response.

Comment: This comment is precisely about this generic relationship that you are willing to specify ("interface Request<T1 extends Response>" ...); whithout any specific on how you will implementing it in your templates.  The point is: why the need to define such a functional relationship in a generic template?  Generic templates have not been implemented in the language for this kind of use.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to link the `Request` and the `Response` in the type definition. They are tied by the `Processor`. Isn't something like

```
interface Requestable {
    ...
}

class Request<T extends Requestable> {
    ...
}

class Response<T extends Requestable> {
    ...
}

class Processor<T extends Requestable> {
    Response<T> process(Request<T> request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

sufficient ? Actually I'm not sure you need generic at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In the context of your code snippet, the request and response need not be generically typed.

Answer (score 0):

There is one use case where it's useful to have a generified Request/Response (or well, at least the Request). If the request is generified to contain the response type, the following call is "typesafe"

```
public <messy define of T> T sendRequest(Request<T> request)
```

Now users of that method will see "typesafe" request-response calling. I'm calling that only "typesafe" because the implementation of that method probably has to cast the responses to T, so ClassCastExceptions are theoretically possible, but in most cases they would be considered as application logic errors.

I would not put the actual fields of Request/Response inside other, just use the generic typeinformation for "typesafe" request-response calling.