# complementary generic classes

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming

I have two abstract classes:
Container, Node

One kind of Container will always contain the same kind of Node, and one kind of node will only belong to its corresponding container:
NodeTypeA is stored in ContainerTypeA, and no other subclass of Node is stored in it.
NodeTypeB is stored in ContainerTypeB, and no other subclass of Node is stored in it. The back-reference from the Node to its Container should also be aware of the type of the Container, so the relation goes in both directions.

I have problems implementing this in Java.

I do it like this:

```
Container<C extends Container<C,N>, N extends Node<C,N>>
Node<C extends Container<C,N>, N extends Node<C,N>>
```

However, when I define the following field in Container, I get an error:

```
private List<N> nodes;
```

The error message says that I should replace N with Node. This seems redundant to me. Why does this happen, and how can I get the program to understand that

```
N
```

should be equal to

```
Node<C,N>
```

Test case:

https://ideone.com/wam0gi

The purpose behind this:

There are many different kinds of Nodes and many different kinds of ways in which they can interact. However, they share some common themes. Container and Node should be abstract classes within which I can define methods and abstract methods to define these common themes. ContainerA and NodeA together will then define one particular method of interaction. I use generics for this because programming gets a lot easier if my IDE is smart enough to know that any Node in a ContainerA is always a NodeA, and the owner of a NodeA is always a ContainerA, so I can avoid some unnecessary type-casting.

(Note: this question is similar but not equal to [Complementary generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641385/complementary-generic-types))

Comment: What is the exact error message? Can you include a minimal, but complete class that results in this error?

Comment: Seems fine here: http://ideone.com/m1Qi2n.  Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: minimal test case: https://ideone.com/wam0gi

Comment: The keyword "abstract" should precede the keyword "class".

Comment: huh. I wrote that in a hurry. Curious that the website's compiler didn't complain about that first, but only about the generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from several trivial errors (`abstract` should precede `class` in java, wrong type variable `L` in constructor of `Node` at line 16, attempt to access a private field at line 18), your semantic problem is at line 18.  The type of `this` is `Node<C,N>`, not `N`.

One way to achieve your goal is to add an abstract method to `Node` which returns `N`, and all subclasses will implement it by returning `this`.

```
abstract protected N me();
```

Then, once you've added a proper setter to `Container`, you'll change line 18 to

```
owner.add( me() );
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the program to understand that
>   `N` should be equal to `Node<C,N>`

They're not equal.  `N` **extends** `Node<C, N>`

```
private List<N> nodes;
```

means a list of some subclass of `Node<C, N>`.

You will have difficulty adding to such a list.

Consider

```
List<N> nodes = ...;

Node<C, N> node = new Node<>(...);
nodes.add(node);  // ERROR because node might not be the right subclass
```

vs

```
List<Node<C, N>> nodes = ...;

Node<C, N> node = new Node<>(...);
nodes.add(node);  // OK.
```

vs

```
List<N> nodes = ...;
N node = new Node<C, N>(...);   // ERROR.  Not all Node<C, N> are N
// N is a sub-type not a super-type of Node<C, N>
nodes.add(node);
```

If `Node` were final, which you say it is not, """

> There are many different kinds of Nodes

""", then you could do

```
N node = (N) new Node<C, N>(..);  // Unchecked conversion
```

but this bending of type erasure rules would be unnecessary even if it were safe in the context of your program.